# Set variable to result of terminal command (Bash)

Tags: bash, openssl, mac-address

So I am TRYING to make a bash file that rotates my MAC address every 10 minutes with a random hexadecimal number assigned each time. I would like to have a variable called `random_hexa` assigned to the result of this command: `openssl rand -hex 6 | sed 's/\(..\)/\1:/g; s/.$//'`. I would then take the variable and use it later on in the script.

Any Idea how to take the result of the `openssl` command and assign it to a variable for later use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Store the variable like so:

```
myVar=$(openssl rand -hex 6 | sed 's/\(..\)/\1:/g; s/.$//')
```

Now `$myVar` can be used to refer to your number:

```
echo $myVar
```

`$()` runs the command inside the parenthesis in a [subshell](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html), which is then stored in the variable `myVar`.  This is called *[command substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html)*.

Answer (score 1):

You want "command substitution".  The traditional syntax is

```
my_new_mac=`openssl rand -hex 6 | sed 's/\(..\)/\1:/g; s/.$//'`
```

Bash also supports this syntax:

```
my_new_mac=$(openssl rand -hex 6 | sed 's/\(..\)/\1:/g; s/.$//')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the result of any command using the `$()` syntax like

`random_hexa=$(openssl...)`