# How to run curl in bash script and keep the result in a variable

Tags: bash, curl

This should have been easy but for some reason it's not:

Trying to run a simple `curl` command, get it's output, and do stuff with it.

```
cmd='curl -v -H "A: B" http://stackoverflow.com'
result=`$cmd | grep "A:"`
...
```

The problem - the header "A: B" is not sent.

The execution of the curl command seems to ignore the header argument, and run curl twice - second time with "B" as host (which obviously fail).

Any idea?

Comment: Am not sure of the issue you are seeing? What is your expected output?

Comment: @elad-tabak I would suggest that you should always check the result of the command like I suggested before storing the same in any variable. This will help you find where the issue lies exactly

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your problem here is that all you are doing on the first command is just setting cmd to equal a string.

Try using `$(...)` to execute the actual command like so:

```
cmd=$(curl -v -H "A: B" http://stackoverflow.com)
```

The result of this will be the actual output from with curl request.

This has been answered many-times see here for example [Set variable to result of terminal command (Bash)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29663820/set-variable-to-result-of-terminal-command-bash)

Answer (score 6):

Keep in mind that cURL debug output is redirected to STDERR - this is so you can pipe the output to another program without the information clobbering the input of the pipe.

Redirect STDERR to STDOUT with the `--stderr -` flag like so:

```
cmd="curl -s -v http://stackoverflow.com -H 'Test:1234' --stderr -"
result=`$cmd | grep "Test:"`
echo $result

./stackoverflow.sh 
> 'Test:1234'
```